# data load from excel into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am loading data into the datagridview from excel. The data is loaded correctly however the validation of the cells is not carried out. I have the validation code in the cell end edit event.

How can it be done?

Comment: do looping to all rows and replace value as validated one ..

Answer (score 0):

Just put the DataGridView into edit mode and then exit the edit mode. That should trigger the EndEdit event.

```
    DataGridView.BeginEdit(True)
    DataGridView.EndEdit()
```